# Flash Proxy Error #2124

Tags: flash, proxy, stream

I got a standard php proxy getting images cross domains.

domain/proxy.php?url=http://images.fandango.com/r85.7.3/ImageRenderer/69/103/images/no_image_69x103.jpg/135631/images/masterrepository/fandango/135631/hp7_2-3d imax poster_lo.jpg

It usually works fine, but on this jpg, I am getting an 
Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type.

Seeing this I plugged the full proxy and image url into the browser and got this php error.

[function.readfile]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Is this because of a corrupted jpg or something with the servers htaccess/config files. Im gonna continue to research the php request stream but any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah, I figured it out. Had to do with dashes in the name of the jpg/png file. I guess it was and encoding thing. Label your images with underscores, not dashes everyone.

thanks